# Combining two select statements

Tags: sql, database, select, where-clause

I have two statements as such:

```
var chgAssociationQuery1 = (from a in sostenuto.PROBLEMS
  join b in sostenuto.S_ASSOCIATION on a.SERVICEREQNO equals b.FROMSERVICEREQNO
  join c in sostenuto.Changes on b.TOSERVICEREQNO equals c.SERVICEREQNO
  where b.FROMSERVICEID == 101001110
     && b.TOSERVICEID == 101001109
     && a.NAME.Contains(name)
  select new { ProblemReqNo = a.SERVICEREQNO,
                  ProblemId = a.SERVICEREQID, 
                ChangeReqNo = c.SERVICEREQNO, 
                   ChangeId = c.SERVICEREQID,
               ChangeNumber = c.CSEBRANCHCHANGE,
               ChangeBranch = c.MAINTBRANCH});

var chgAssociationQuery2 = (from a in sostenuto.PROBLEMS
  join b in sostenuto.S_ASSOCIATION on a.SERVICEREQNO equals b.TOSERVICEREQNO
  join c in sostenuto.Changes on b.FROMSERVICEREQNO equals c.SERVICEREQNO
  where b.FROMSERVICEID == 101001109
     && b.TOSERVICEID == 101001110
     && a.NAME.Contains(name)
  select new { ProblemReqNo = a.SERVICEREQNO,
                  ProblemId = a.SERVICEREQID,
                ChangeReqNo = c.SERVICEREQNO,
                   ChangeId = c.SERVICEREQID,
               ChangeNumber = c.CSEBRANCHCHANGE,
               ChangeBranch = c.MAINTBRANCH });

var vProblemxChange = chgAssociationQuery1.Union(from a in chgAssociationQuery2 select a);
```

and I'm wanting to be able to combine them into one; as currently it loops through the database twice - which is very inefficient. I've tried researching how to put multiple select statements within the where clause but I can't seem to find anything that I can understand.

Can anyone shed some light on my situation?

I tried modifying an answer below:

```
        var vProblemxChange =
      (from a in sostenuto.PROBLEMS
       join b in sostenuto.S_ASSOCIATION on a.SERVICEREQNO equals b.FROMSERVICEREQNO
       join c in sostenuto.Changes on b.TOSERVICEREQNO equals c.SERVICEREQNO
       join z in sostenuto.S_ASSOCIATION on a.SERVICEREQNO equals z.TOSERVICEREQNO
       join y in sostenuto.Changes on z.FROMSERVICEREQNO equals y.SERVICEREQNO
       where ((b.FROMSERVICEID == 101001110 && b.TOSERVICEID == 101001109 && a.NAME.Contains(name)) ||
              (z.FROMSERVICEID == 101001109 && z.TOSERVICEID == 101001110) && a.NAME.Contains(name))
          && a.NAME.Contains(name)
       select new
       {
           ProblemReqNo = a.SERVICEREQNO,
           ProblemId = a.SERVICEREQID,
           ChangeReqNo = c.SERVICEREQNO,
           ChangeId = c.SERVICEREQID,
           ChangeNumber = c.CSEBRANCHCHANGE,
           ChangeBranch = c.MAINTBRANCH
       });
```

However as I'm trying to access different joins based on the where clause, I can't change that in the select statement; for example, if the second half of the OR is true, it should use a and y in the select rather than a and c.

Comment: Do you want to know how to combin to queries in general, or are you interested in one simplified query for the given example? Because the only difference I can see in the queries is the FROMSERVICEID and TOSERVICE ID, so maybe you want to extract that information from the rest of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this

```
var chgAssociationQuery1 = ((from a in sostenuto.PROBLEMS
                                         join b in sostenuto.S_ASSOCIATION on a.SERVICEREQNO equals b.FROMSERVICEREQNO
                                         join c in sostenuto.Changes on b.TOSERVICEREQNO equals c.SERVICEREQNO
                                         where b.FROMSERVICEID == 101001110
                                               && b.TOSERVICEID == 101001109
                                               && a.NAME.Contains(name)
                                         select new { ProblemReqNo = a.SERVICEREQNO, ProblemId = a.SERVICEREQID, ChangeReqNo = c.SERVICEREQNO, ChangeId = c.SERVICEREQID, ChangeNumber = c.CSEBRANCHCHANGE, ChangeBranch = c.MAINTBRANCH})
                                       .Union(from a in sostenuto.PROBLEMS
                                         join b in sostenuto.S_ASSOCIATION on a.SERVICEREQNO equals b.TOSERVICEREQNO
                                         join c in sostenuto.Changes on b.FROMSERVICEREQNO equals c.SERVICEREQNO
                                         where b.FROMSERVICEID == 101001109
                                               && b.TOSERVICEID == 101001110
                                               && a.NAME.Contains(name)
                                            select new { ProblemReqNo = a.SERVICEREQNO, ProblemId = a.SERVICEREQID, ChangeReqNo = c.SERVICEREQNO, ChangeId = c.SERVICEREQID, ChangeNumber = c.CSEBRANCHCHANGE, ChangeBranch = c.MAINTBRANCH })).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you this worked and has improved my performance as I hoped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var chgAssociationQuery1 = 
      (from a in sostenuto.PROBLEMS
       join b in sostenuto.S_ASSOCIATION on a.SERVICEREQNO equals b.FROMSERVICEREQNO
       join c in sostenuto.Changes on b.TOSERVICEREQNO equals c.SERVICEREQNO
       where ((b.FROMSERVICEID == 101001110 && b.TOSERVICEID == 101001109) ||
              (b.FROMSERVICEID == 101001109 && b.TOSERVICEID == 101001110))
          && a.NAME.Contains(name)
       select new { 
                      ProblemReqNo = a.SERVICEREQNO, 
                      ProblemId = a.SERVICEREQID, 
                      ChangeReqNo = c.SERVICEREQNO, 
                      ChangeId = c.SERVICEREQID, 
                      ChangeNumber = c.CSEBRANCHCHANGE, 
                      ChangeBranch = c.MAINTBRANCH
                  }).Distinct();
```

Comment: I did try this, however it gave incorrect results - the other answer yielded the correct results and improved my performance but thank you :)

Comment: @Craig, I believe it is because of duplicates? I have added distinct to the result. It should be faster then version with unions.

Comment: I think the joins aren't fully complete - it doesn't join 'sostenuto.S_ASSOCIATION on a.SERVICEREQNO equals b.TOSERVICEREQNO' or 'sostenuto.Changes on b.FROMSERVICEREQNO equals c.SERVICEREQNO'. I'm picking this project from a colleague and have very very limited exposure to SQL

Comment: @Craig, common, I have copied that from your question. It is the same join as in your question. Just copy this and see if you get the correct result. You should. It should give the same result as in accepted answer but without overhear on unions, which is very heavy.

Comment: I've just tested your code against the original and I'm afraid it doesn't give the correct result. The reason is the joins; in the first query it has different joins to the 2nd; whereas your answer only contains the first queries joins. So I'm assuming that's giving the wrong answer. I've tried adding in the 2nd queries joins to your answer but as it's joining different tables, i can't portray that in the select statement. Please see the edit on my original post to see what I mean

Comment: @Craid, yes you are correct, my bad. I didin't notice that there are different join. Sorry.